# VIM: Filename passed to source from within SourcePre autocommand?

Tags: vim

Is there some way in which I can read the filename being passed to source, when the SourcePre autocommand is triggered?

eg:

```
au SourcePre */plugin/*.vim set runtimepath=/usr/share/vim/vim71/{INSERT-Plugin-Dir-Name}
source /root/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim_-_Elegant_buffer_explorer/plugin/minibufexpl.vim
```

I'd like to replace this `{INSERT-Plugin-Dir-Name}` with `"minibufexpl.vim_-_Elegant_buffer_explorer"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<afile>` to get name of the file being sourced.  You can use `expand()` to turn it into a full path and get the bit you want.  For example, in your line:

```
source /root/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim_-_Elegant_buffer_explorer/plugin/minibufexpl.vim
```

You could do:

```
expand('<afile>:p:h:h')
```

The `:p` turns it into a full path (in case you do `cd /path/to/plugin`, `:source filename.vim`); each `:h` strips one part of the path off the end.

Note that this won't work in a `:set` line.  Use `:let-&` instead:

```
let &runtimepath='/usr/share/vim/vim71/' . expand('<afile>:p:h:h>')
```

See:

```
:help SourcePre
:help expand()
:help :let-&
```